How to remain vscode inlinesuggestion visible
currently I'm developing a vscode extension which provides inline completion function. This is the command I defined how vscode accepts inline suggestion:
      {
        "command": "editor.action.inlineSuggest.commit",
        "key": "tab",
        "mac": "tab",
        "when": "inlineSuggestionHasIndentationLessThanTabSize && inlineSuggestionVisible && !editorHoverFocused && !editorTabMovesFocus && !suggestWidgetVisible"
      },

The problem is when inline suggestion has larger indentation than tab size, inline suggestion will disappear after i pressed tab. What I want is inline suggestion remains visible until indentation less than tab size, after that the suggestion will be accepted when I press tab. Can somebody help me with this issue?
